# Is there something wrong with this line of Python code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried this line of code, and it kept giving me the SyntaxError.

```
print('/' / '-' / '\' / '|' * 30, end='\r')
                                          ^
```

It pointed on the brackets.
Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: what do you want this line of code to do? You are dividing strings (`'/' / '-'`). That's not a thing in python.

Comment: Your backward and forward slashes seem to be incorrect. Can you check those? Also, add the input and expected output in your question.

Comment: The syntax is because you're escaping the `\'` rather than creating a string with a slash in it `'\\'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already mentioned in comments, the immediate problem is the syntax error caused by the un-escaped `\`, causing the `\` to escape the following `'`. Next, there is the problem of `/` applied to strings... Python does not really know what you are trying to achieve with that.

From your choice of characters and the `end="\r"`, I guess that you are trying to create some kind of "spinner" animation. For this, you could use modulo `%` to access the matching character, then use a proper `for` loop to `print` them. Also, you might have to `flush` the print stream besides resetting it to the start of the line, and you might want to add some waiting time in between.

```
import time
for i in range(30):
    print("/-\\|"[i%4], end="\r", flush=True)
    time.sleep(0.3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax error because you are escaping a character: `\'`

My guessing is that you need to escape the special character: `'\\'`

Comment: but I don't want double slashes

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure if "end='\r'" is a valid argument. But problem is that quotes need to closed. That is why `print("'/' / '-' / '\' / '|'"*30+"\r")` works 
while  `print('/' / '-' / '\' / '|'*30+"\r")` does not.

In a nutshell, use `print("'/' / '-' / '\' / '|'"*30+"\r")`.

Comment: it does work, but what I mean is displaying these 4 symbols / - \ | in a loop for n times. When it's time to move to the new one, the old one will be deleted