# How to output message in Python and then delete it in output

Tags: python, python-3.x

so i want to output '|' and the remove it and paste '/' instead (in one line) so it will make animation.

```
import time


animation = '|'
print(animation)

time.sleep(0.5)

animation = animation.replace('|', '/')
print(animation)
```

Comment: More recent: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59031604/1639625

Comment: i was thinking more this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18937058/clear-screen-in-shell/47296211

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell, you need to output `\r` character, which is a [carriage RETURN command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return). It will put the caret to the start of the line in the console. Next output will basically rewrite the line contents.

```
import sys, time

i = 0
while True:
    sys.stdout.write('/-\\|'[i%4])
    time.sleep(0.5)
    sys.stdout.write('\r')
    i += 1
```